# ADF - How to disable mapping in Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to backup data from CosmosDB to Storage.

I found DB's data is different from Storage's data when data has a value ended with `.000Z` .

Data in CosmosDB like this:

```json
{
  "start": "2021-09-12T15:00:00.000Z",
  "end": "2022-10-30T15:00:00.000Z",
}
```

Data in Storage like this:

```json
{
  "start": "2021-09-12T15:00:00Z",
  "end": "2022-10-30T15:00:00Z",
}
```

**How can I let them be same?**

Comment: I am assuming you are storing them as JSON files in storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.000` represents the fraction of seconds in the timestamp and `Z` represents the UTC timezone in ISO-8601 date format. And, `00Z` corresponds to midnight in Greenwich ONLY.

The recommended format for DateTime strings in Azure Cosmos DB is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ` which follows the ISO 8601 UTC standard. Where, `.fffffff` seven-digit fractional seconds

You may enable or disable this `Detect datetime` property to get this as a string instead. Also, if you choose sink as `.json` there is very less option (such as ability to choose column format if available for `.csv` sink).

[image]

further you can checkout [Configure Azure Cosmos DB account with periodic backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/configure-periodic-backup-restore)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the mapping first to check what data types are getting mapped for this field

I had one such use case where data types were different and I tried following steps to resolve:

1. Click on Import in Mapping section of Copy Activity
2. Check if all columns are correctly mapped
3. Extract the JSON from Copy activity for mapping
4. Check the data types being mapped in the JSON
5. If the data type for the field is not matching then you will get different data
6. To match the data you will have to dynamically pass the JSON which is explained in detail in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b27gmOufge4